# how can i delet brackets with this command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, brackets

I want to delete brackets from this list with this kind of code or with a recursive function
first of all please let me know what's wrong whit these codes and then please give me the correct code
thanks

```
def fun(a) :
    x = []
    while a[0,len(a)+1] is not int :
        for i in range(len(a)):
            b = a[i]
            b = b[0] if b is not int else b
            if b is int :
                x.append(b)
                break
    return x
l = [[1],[2],[[3]],[[[4]]]]
print(fun(l))
```

or

```
L = [[[[1]]], [[2, 3, 4, 5]], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
x = []
b = []
for i in range(len(L)):
    while L[i] is not int:
        if b is int:
            L[i].append(x)
            break
        else:
            b = L[i]
            b = b[0]
            L[i] = b
print(L)
```

Comment: Your line `if b is int:` is not working. It should be `if type(b) is int:` or, even better, `if isinstance(b, int):`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `type(x) is ...` you should generally use `isinstance`. Here is a simple, recursive unpack function.

```
def unpack(item):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for subitem in item:
            yield from unpack(subitem)
    else:
        yield item

L = [[[[1]]], [[2, 3, 4, 5]], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
L2 = list(unpack(L)) # L2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with lists that consist of multiple nested-lists (e.g. `[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]`), you'll need something like this:

```py
def check(l):
    # check if all extra brackets removed
    for x in l:
        if not type(x) is int:
            return False
    return True

def fun(l):
    new_l = []
    for x in l:
        if type(x) is int:
            new_l.append(x)
        else:
            # x is list
            new_l.extend(fun(x))
    return new_l
```

alternatively:

```py
def bar(l):
    return str(l).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",")
```

Comment: Your `bar` example should not be used because it converts the contents which were initially integers to strings. And also where is your `check` function used and why do you need it?

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps:

```
L_cleaned = [eval(i) if len(i)!=0 else '' for i in str(L).replace('[', '').replace(']','').split(',')]
```

Comment: hi it has a problem if i add a bracket in index 1 of a list in an other list like
L = [[6,[3], 7, 8],]

Comment: I updated the code with a better and faster one :)

Comment: This is very easy to exploit a python code injection vulnerability. Really best not to use `eval` especially for something like this.

Comment: Also it fails with an empty list `[]` as you end up running `eval('')`

Comment: I fixed the code to handle empty lists as well. Also, since the values in the lists are of int type, there's no harm in using eval to make the code simpler.